# width in IE must be 2 px more than ff and ch

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, cross-browser

Hi I'm writing a Web calculator and the main div's width in ie needs to be 2 more px than in ff and ch, which makes it look a little loose in ff and ch or completely broken in ie.
[here's a link to the calc](http://yovelzack.fav.cc/) and a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vrs42/3/). If someone can help me reduce those two px's (#main{width: 186px;} is what I wan't to get) or at least make the buttons spread evenly in all browsers, it'd be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try changing the width to 186px? the hole layout brakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an IE hack ?

Something like

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
  #main {
    width: 188px !important;
  }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

in your head markup for IE up to version 8 here (changeable) and put your css back to 186px in your css file.

That's a bit cheating, but if that's alright with you...

Comment: Looks like you believe for some reason I'm using IE 8 or lower, which I'm not. It does the job when I change your code to IE 9, so thanks. But I admit I was hoping for a more conventional solution. BTW why is it an IE hack (and what language is it with the if-endif?)

Answer (score 0):

add following script

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById('main');
var divWidth = parseInt(mainDiv.style.width);
if(navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
mainDiv.style.width = divWidth + 2 + 'px';
}
```